# Running a keyboard shortcut at startup (FN + WIN) automatically

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have a Redragon K580 keyboard with an option to lock the Windows key with a shortcut (FN + Win). The problem is that it doesn't stay locked permanently and I have to do it after each reboot and most of the time I forget to do it every time before gaming. I don't want to disable it permanently with registry hacks because I tend to use it when I am not gaming.

So, is there any way to automatically disable it at startup with some VBS SendKey script or with AutoHotKey?
Thanks,

Comment: Functionality like that would usually be implemented “in hardware” (in the keyboard’s firmware).

Comment: Or in software, in the keyboard's driver suite.

Comment: Unfortunately, its software only has the option to change the RGB lighting patterns and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Create and run .ahk script:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance force

If not A_IsAdmin ; For Win10 users
    Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"

Menu Tray, Icon, shell32.dll, 110
Menu Tray, NoStandard
Menu Tray, Add, Block [Win], +LWin
Menu Tray, Add, AutoStart, AutoStartSwitch
Menu Tray, Add, Exit, Exit

winBlock := True ; Blocked at start
If winBlock
    Menu Tray, Check, Block [Win]

SplitPath, A_ScriptName, , , , OutNameNoExt
LinkFile := A_StartupCommon "\" OutNameNoExt ".lnk"
If FileExist(LinkFile)
    Menu Tray, Check, AutoStart
Return

+LWin:: ; Shift + LWin — toggle block
    winBlock := Not winBlock
    Menu Tray, Togglecheck, Block [Win]
    Return

#If winBlock
    LWin::Return ; Block
#If

AutoStartSwitch:
    If FileExist(LinkFile)
        FileDelete % LinkFile
    Else
      FileCreateShortcut % A_ScriptFullPath, % LinkFile, % A_ScriptDir
  Menu Tray, ToggleCheck, AutoStart
    Return

Exit:
    ExitApp
```

Use `Shift + LWin` to block/unblock `LWin` button.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution -

1. Install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/)
2. Create 'Disable LWin.ahk` with the following code -

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1.37

#NoEnv  
#SingleInstance force  
SendMode Input 
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

LWinIndex := 1

LWin::
If LWinIndex = 1 {  ; left win button is disabled
    ToolTip LWin Disabled
    SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, -1000
    Return
    }
Else Send {LWin}  ; left win button is enabled
Return

!Esc::  ; Alt + Esc
If LWinIndex = 1 {
    LWinIndex := 0
    ToolTip LWin Enabled
    SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, -1000
    }
Rlse {
    LWinIndex := 1
    ToolTip LWin Disabled
    SetTimer, RemoveToolTip, -1000
    }
Return

RemoveToolTip:
ToolTip
Return
```

3. Place `Disable LWin.ahk` or shortcut to this ahk in startup folder `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`
   This should run the AHK on startup and disable <kbd>**LWin**</kbd> when you login.
4. Done!

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> should enable or disable <kbd>LWin</kbd>.
I have used `!Esc` here because AHK doesn't recognise <kbd>**Fn**</kbd> button on most keyboards.